# poker full house binomial overcounting

Tags: probability, combinatorics

I know that the probability of getting a full house in poker is:
$$ \frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot \binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$
Can someone please explain why we are not overcounting here. I believe that it does not matter whether we choose the 3 of a kind first and then the 2 of kind or if we do it vice versa choosing the 2 of a kind first and then choose the 3 of a kind second. If this is true then we would need to multiply that formula by $ \frac 12 $ to end up with $$ \frac 12 \cdot \frac{13 \cdot 12 \cdot \binom{4}{3} \cdot \binom{4}{2}}{\binom{52}{5}}.$$ Why is my thinking wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: For this and probabilities for various other poker hands, I suggest you look at [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poker_probability). Many examples help with definitions, undercount, and overcount issues if you study them. // If I understand your question correctly, I think it's because the order of selecting cards (any of them) does not matter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't matter which one you choose first, but whichever you choose first, each hand is counted exactly once, so there's no overcounting.

If you choose the $3$-of-a-kind first, and then the pair, the number of hands is the value of the expression
$${\small{\binom{13}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{3}}}{\small{\binom{12}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{2}}}$$

If you choose the pair first, and then the $3$-of-a-kind, the number of hands is the value of the expression
$${\small{\binom{13}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{2}}}{\small{\binom{12}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{3}}}$$
yeilding the same count.

But with either choice, each hand is counted exactly once.

As a way to see it, consider a reduced deck with $3$ suits, and $2$ ranks; $Q\;$(Queens), and $J\;$(Jacks), where for each rank, there is one of each suit, so the deck consists of $3$ Queens, and $3$ Jacks. Since the deck has $6$ cards, there are only $6$ different $5$-card hands, and clearly, every hand is a full house. Thus, the count for the number of full house hands is $6$, which is the same count as you would get by evaluating the expression
$${\small{\binom{2}{1}}}{\small{\binom{3}{3}}}{\small{\binom{1}{1}}}{\small{\binom{3}{2}}}$$
So it would be incorrect to divide by $2$.

As an example where you *would* need to divide by $2$, consider the number of hands which are two-pairs . . .

Choosing the first pair, then choosing the second pair, then choosing the remaining card, would yield a doubled count, since the hand $\text{XXYYZ}$ is the same as the hand $\text{YYXXZ}$. Hence, the correct count (using a standard $52$-card deck) would be
$$\left({\small{\frac{1}{2}}}\right)\left({\small{\binom{13}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{2}}}{\small{\binom{12}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{2}}}{\small{\binom{11}{1}}}{\small{\binom{4}{1}}}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

> I believe that it does not matter whether we choose the 3 of a kind first and then the 2 of kind or if we do it vice versa choosing the 2 of a kind first and then choose the 3 of a kind second.

Correct.  You can do it whichever way you like.  But there is only double counting if you do it **both** ways, and you haven't - in your answer you have (I think) done it the first way.  You could do it the second way **instead** and you would get the same answer, but it's only if you did it the second way **as well** that you would have to divide by $2$.

A rough analogy: put your full house cards down on the table and count them.  If you count them from left to right **and** from right to left you will get an answer of $10$ and you have to divide by $2$.  But if you only count them from left to right **or** right to left and not both, then you will get the right answer straight away, whichever direction you count.

Hope this helps!